# Options for building cross-platform applications using HTML as the GUI?

Tags: html, css, flutter, qt, cross-platform

I would like to build a cross platform application on Win, MacOS, Linux, Ios, Android, and Browser extension.

The application will call some system APIs, such as microphone and camera, read screen, create system tray, etc.

I also want to use HTML and CSS to build the GUI because I am only confident in precise control down to the pixel level using HTML + CSS.

Are there any options available that fit my needs?

After some research, it looks like Qt with QWebview, and Flutter with Webview could be options.